# How can I make a generic UIViewRepresentable struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want build a struct that it takes a UI type as input and it present that UI in SwiftUI, for example I have this down codes for UILabel and UIButton, I want make a generic one to free me from making an individual struct for each UI from UIKit:

```
struct UILabelViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let configuration: (UILabel) -> ()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
       return UILabel()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}



struct UIButtonViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let configuration: (UIButton) -> ()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
       return UIButton()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

Here what I tried so far:

```
struct GenericUIViewRepresentable<UIViewType: UIView>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let uiViewType: UIViewType
    let configuration: (UIViewType) -> ()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        return uiViewType
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

it makes an error when I want use it:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel.Type' to expected argument type 'UIView'

So I know about the error, I want make my code works and it makes me free to type all UIKit UI that I want.

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GenericUIViewRepresentable(uiViewType: UILabel, configuration: { label in
            label.text = "Hello, World!"
        })

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass in the `UIView` type, not just a `UIView` instance. This means you want to do `UIViewType.Type` rather than `UIViewType`.

Code:

```
struct GenericUIViewRepresentable<UIView: UIKit.UIView>: UIViewRepresentable {
    let uiViewType: UIView.Type
    let configuration: (UIView) -> ()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        uiViewType.init()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world!")

            GenericUIViewRepresentable(uiViewType: UILabel.self) { label in
                label.text = "Other text!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID455) on swift.org is where you can learn more about metatype types.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Putting `Type` on the end of a name doesn't make any sense, because the concept is recursive. i.e. `UIViewType` has the same meaning as `UIViewTypeTypeTypeTypeType…`. Just call it `UIView: UIKit.UIView`.

Comment: @Jessy True, I should have changed the name from the original question. Thanks for the advice, updated the answer :)